# /index.php/ appearing in generated clean URIs

Tags: 8, uri

I have a Drupal 8 site with clean URLs. Recently, URLs are similar to example.com/index.php/page-url-alias. The page still loads correctly, but I don't want the `index.php` part to be indexed.

If I empty the cache, the URLs are shown correctly.

How can I force Drupal not to add index.php in the URLs it generates?

Comment: So when do they appear with index.php then if you cleared the cache? Maybe some wring custom links?

Comment: @schlicki No, they disappear when the cache is cleared. The path aliases all look good.

Comment: But then its fine isn't it? Or when do they show up wrong again?

Comment: They show up again eventually.

Comment: Yes, that's a strange behavior in D8, very erratic and unpredictably. And this poisons all other internal links in the browser session. You can fix this with the module Redirect, see my answer. Does anybody know where this is coming from? You shouldn't need a module to fix this.

Comment: @4k4 I already have Redirect set up as in your screenshot. Drupal _is_ using the alias, but with `/index.php/` inserted. I think a hook might be the best way to go.

Comment: At least Redirect stops links with `/index.php/` by redirecting them to clean urls. Without Redirect it gets much worse when a user clicks on an unclean url the rest of the browser session will be in the `/index.php/` namespace. More important I think is that you avoid with Redirect that unclean urls are indexed by search machines.

Comment: @Tim, until now I was not able to reproduce this bug in dev. Only had this in production. Have you more details, when and where this happens?

Comment: No, not currently.

Comment: @4k4 and Tim, have either of you figured this one out. Just stumbled upon this on a site too.

Comment: @Mescalito, in this topic is the solution I'm using and more background info https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/239042/sporadic-permissions-issue/

Answer (score 2):

In D7 [Global Redirect](https://www.drupal.org/project/globalredirect) was used for clean urls. In D8 this was moved to the module Redirect.

The global redirect options in [Redirect](https://www.drupal.org/project/redirect) are set by default to avoid unclean urls:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Might not be a clean way but you could do this via your .htaccess,
Something along the lines of this:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET.*index\.php [NC]
RewriteRule (.*?)index\.php/*(.*) /$1$2 [R=301,NE,L]
```

Not sure if this works in drupal, i have used this on other CMS.

Comment: I thought about mod_rewrite as an interim solution, I was wondering if there is a Drupal-specific way of preventing it.