# Admin toolbar loads index.php/*

Tags: 9, toolbar

I am using Drupal 9 all the admin tool bar menu options loads the URL with /index.php/admin/config/* as URL

I have the clean URL programmed in .htaccess, but still the menu load only index.php/ URLs

How do I fix it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sporadic permissions issue](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/239042/sporadic-permissions-issue)

Answer (score 2):

This is an [old issue](https://www.drupal.org/node/2641118) still not resolved. In [this topic](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/239042/sporadic-permissions-issue) you find three fixes. The core patch from the issue would be the most obvious, but now, 5 years later, it is the least favorable, because the module [Redirect](https://www.drupal.org/project/redirect) is better maintained. If you don't want to install a module then you can use the .htaccess solution.

After implementing the fix clear the cache. This removes all unclean URLs from cache and the fix prevents that new ones a generated by site visitors still using the old links, through bookmarks or autocompletes for example.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue by intentionally loading the URL with website.com/admin/ and apply clean URLs and clear cache

Now all the menus adjusted to /admin/ pattern

My simple xml sitemap also got fixed

it seems the PHP code is written in such a way to read the current loaded URL, if it is has the index.php then the program applies that value to the database