# Keep randomly getting /index.php/ in link Urls with Pantheon (nginx)

Tags: uri, 8

I have a live D8 pantheon site and keep randomly getting `index.php` in the menu link urls. It's now happened  four or five times. We've set a base url for the sitemap, so it has prevented the sitemap from including `index.php` (which it did the first time). And we've also redirected from `/index.php` to `/` in settings.php, which works fine.

But still, today, on the live site, we found that a bunch of menu links randomly had /index.php/ in the paths (it was all the links referencing a node). And if we clear the cache or just wait 20 minutes, it magically fixes itself.

I haven't had enough time with the problem persisting to successfully debug it. This is similar to the following link, but the solution here is for apache, whereas pantheon uses nginx. https://www.drupal.org/forum/support/post-installation/2016-09-19/how-to-remove-indexphp-from-urls

Anyone ever run into this or have an idea where to start prodding next? Any help or debugging suggestions are greatly appreciated! Thanks.

Drupal 8.5.3
nginx/1.8.1

Comment: what's your nginx configuration for location? or is nginx.conf is not available on pantheon? ..

Comment: That's something Pantheon controls...we don't have access to nginx configuration... I did ask pantheon about this issue and they said they don't think it's anything on their end. But i'm not fully convinced of that.

Comment: You can redirect the unclean urls by installing the module Redirect, see https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/228893/index-php-appearing-in-generated-clean-uris/228903#228903, then this should stop after some time.

Comment: I had the module on but didn't check the box to force clean Urls. Since I don't know how to reproduce the problem, I guess time will tell if that fixes it. Thanks!